# Is the Sy basis of Spin not orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, quantum-mechanics, change-of-basis

According to [Wikipedia on Spin $1/2$ particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenspinor#The_spin_1/2_particle), the vectors of the $S_y$ basis, with respect to the $S_z$ basis, are:
\begin{bmatrix} 0.707 \\ 0.707*i \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 0.707 \\ -0.707*i \end{bmatrix}

I check their orthogonality by doing the dot product:

$0.707*0.707 + (0.707*i)*(-0.707*i) = 0.5 - 0.5*i^2 = 0.5 + 0.5 = 1$

Since it's not zero, the elements are not orthogonal. Doesn't that mean that they can't form a basis?

($S_z$ and $S_x$ are indeed orthogonal)

Comment: You forgot complex conjugation in the scalar product. Eigenvectors of an hermitian operator related to different eigenvalues are always orthogonal.

Comment: ohhhhh that makes sense, thank you